# Unable to do overlap block transfer in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have made a program in Assembly language(nasm) to do overlap block transfer i.e., if one of my array contains '10, 20, 30, 40, 50'(without quotes) then after overlapping of for example 2 elements my resulting array should contain '10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50'(without quotes). But my problem is when I display my resultant array it only shows '10, 20, 10, 20, 30'(without quotes). I am unable to figure out the problem. Below shown is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
%macro disp 2                               ; Display macro
mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,%1
mov rdx,%2
syscall
%endm

%macro accept 2                             ; Accept Data
mov rax,0
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,%1
mov rdx,%2
syscall
%endm

global _start           

section .data                               ; Data Section
arr db 10h,20h,30h,40h,50h
msg1: db "",10,"Input array is",10
len1: equ $-msg1
msg2: db "",10,"Output array is",10
len2: equ $-msg2
msg3: db "Enter the number to be overlapped",10
len3: equ $-msg3

section .bss                                ; Bss Section
arr1 resb 10
ar1 resb 10
ar2 resb 10
cn resb 2



section .text                               ; Text Section
_start:                                 ; Tell linker entry point

disp msg3,len3                                      
accept cn,2                         ; Accept No. of overlaps to be done from user

mov cl,[cn]                         ; Convert the cn from ASCII
sub cl,'0'                          ; to Decimal

mov rsi,arr
mov rdi,arr1


up: mov al,[rsi]                            ; Copy the contents from arr to arr1 for cn times
mov [rdi],al
inc rsi
inc rdi
dec cl
jnz up

mov rsi,arr                         ; Now copy the contents again from starting
mov cl,5

up_a:   mov al,[rsi]
mov [rdi],al
inc rsi
inc rdi
dec cl
jnz up_a

mov rsi,arr                         ; Convert to ASCII
mov rdi,ar1
mov rdx,5
call asci

mov rsi,arr1                            ; Convert to ASCII
mov rdi,ar2
mov rdx,10
call asci

disp msg1,len1
disp ar1,10

disp msg2,len2
disp ar2,10

mov rax,60
mov rdi,0
syscall


asci:  

up1:    mov al,[rsi]        ;Move the first element pointed by rsi into al register
    mov cl,2        ;The loop counter (there are 2 digits)

up2:    rol al,4        ; Rotate the contents of al 4 bits to the left. What were
                    ; previously the most significant bit will now be in
                    ; the least significant bit of al. This is done because
                    ; we want to print the most significant digit first. 
    mov bl,al       ; Make a copy of the rotated version of al.
    and al,0Fh      ; Keep the least significant bit of al and set all other
                    ; bits of al to 0.
    cmp al,09h      ; al will now be in the range 0..15. Is it greater than 9?
    ja dn1          ; ..if so, jump to dn1.
    add al,30h      ; al was in the range 0..9. The characters '0'..'9' are encoded as
                    ; 30h..39h in ASCII, so add 30h to convert into a character.
    jmp dn2         ; We're done with this case.

dn1:    add al,37h      ; al is in the range 10..15. The characters 'A'..'F' are encoded as
                        ; 41h..46h in ASCII, so add 37h to convert into a character.

dn2:   mov [rdi],al     ; Store the character in the buffer pointed to by rdi.
    mov al,bl       ; Restore al to the value it had right after the rol. So on the
                    ; next iteration we'll be processing what were originally the
                    ; second most significant bit, and so on.
    inc rdi         ; Increment the buffer pointer.
    dec cl          ; Decrement the loop counter.
    jnz up2         ; Repeat for all 2 digits.

        inc rsi         ; rsi now points to the next location
    dec rdx         ; Decrement the loop counter
    jnz up1         ; Repeat for all 5 array elements

ret
```

Comment: How does your `asci` function work?  why not just `add al, '0'`, instead of your rotate/mask/compare/`add al, '7'`?  Also, in the normal ABI, rbx is call-preserved, but you use `bl` as a scratch register.  Are you sure you're not writing beyond the end of the array?  e.g. **maybe your 2nd call to `asci` clobbers the end of the result from the first call, since you're only using 10 byte output buffers.**  I haven't figured out where your code detects the length of the array (which varies depending on the amount of overlap).

Comment: I have already tried ` add al,'0' ` to convert to ASCII but the problem was that I was using an array. Moreover if I use that code it shows segmentation fault. So I used the above written procedure to convert into ASCII. I think you want to understand how that ASCII function works, if that is so then take a look at the program again, I have added comments to make it better understandable. Now for your second question, are you suggesting to use syscall after my first ASCII call ?

Comment: Oh right, converting to a hex digit requires a branch on `0-9` vs. `A-F`, I see what that's about now that you've improved the comments.  For buffer handling:  You don't need two separate ascii buffers if you convert/print, convert/print, instead of convert,convert / print,print.  But you still need the right amount of space reserved, like Score_Under's answer points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overlapped copy works fine. What doesn't work is how you're calling the display routine.

First, you have only allocated 10 bytes for your output, when you're copying a hex representation of a 10-byte array into it (so you need 20 bytes!)

Second, you are only printing 10 bytes. Since we're changing the length to 20, you should change the print length to that too.

Here is the change in unified diff form:

```
--- orig.s  2016-01-16 19:55:33.268099503 +0000
+++ modified.s  2016-01-16 19:58:24.952600505 +0000
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@
 section .bss                                ; Bss Section
 arr1 resb 10
 ar1 resb 10
-ar2 resb 10
+ar2 resb 20
 cn resb 2


@@ -77,7 +77,7 @@
 disp ar1,10

 disp msg2,len2
-disp ar2,10
+disp ar2,20

 mov rax,60
 mov rdi,0
```

Despite having the wrong length for the array and the printing of the array, you already had the right lengths in the call to the `asci` function.